# Chrome ( 103 ) dev tool doesn't show "progress::-webkit-progress-value"

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

`Chrome ( 103 )` dev tool doesn't show below values under `Styles` tab.

I could see this value in FF ( 102 ) under dev tool middle section at top.

Is this bug with Chrome or they have changed location somewhere else ?

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: radial-gradient(6px at 96%, white, white 4px, transparent),
    linear-gradient(to right, hsl(6, 100%, 80%), hsl(335, 100%, 65%));
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: transparent;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: radial-gradient(6px at 98%, white, white 4px, transparent),
    linear-gradient(to right, hsl(6, 100%, 80%), hsl(335, 100%, 65%));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you have enabled "Show user agent Shadow DOM" in the Settings > Preferences > Elements
   [image]
2. You need to have `appearance: none` on the progress element for the pseudo elements to take effect. Then you can inspect the shadow DOM and see the corresponding values in the **Styles** pane.

[image]